# Reset / Retrieve BIOS admin password on a laptop (Asus UX430UA)

Tags: bios, passwords, asus-laptop, password-recovery

I need to remove the admin password in the BIOS in a ASUS UX430UA laptop.
I am running dual-boot with Windows 10 64bit and kubuntu.
I tried using CMOS De-Animator 2 and 3 through windows, but neither worked.

I have contacted the ASUS but the only solution they offered is to send the computer to them and they will replace the motherboard.
They did mention that there is no master password, and that "we do not have a way to reset the bios password".

This laptop is used daily and it is a problem to send it for several weeks for such repair.

I wondered if there is a way that I will be able to reset / retrieve the password myself.
I have seen some tips about using bootable flash drive with kali linux, but the bios is set on secure boot which prevents kali linux from booting (and I cannot change it without the admin password).

The admin password prevents me from changing most of the BIOS settings, but does not prevent me from loading windows / kubuntu.

Comment: Most modern laptops do not have a way to reset the CMOS battery for security reasons.

Comment: See if this works>>>>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6clmtd7Nno

Comment: doesn't work, nothing happens when I press alt+r.

Answer (score 1):

I just did an ASUS BIOS password reset using this site.
https://www.biosbug.com/asus.php

<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and write down the date.

If you type the date in and make a mistake, the backspace will clear, but the result will be wrong, Refresh the site and try again. I got in on second password sent.